# What is the name of a function with four parentheses

Tags: javascript

For example:

```
const factory = {
    myFunc(str1) {
    console.log(str1)
    return (comp) => {
        return comp;
    }
  }
}

console.log(factory.myFunc("foo")("bar"));
```

The myFunc has four parentheses: `factory.myFunc("foo")("bar")`.

How do you call such a function?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function

Comment: It's just a function that returns another function. It's nothing special. Depending on how it's used it could be a function factory or partial function or currying etc. It's just shortcut for ``var func2 = factory.myFunc('foo'); console.log(func2('bar'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its called `function currying`.

Actually read it like `factory.myFunc("foo")` is returning a function (say x) and calling that function immediately with "bar" argument (like x("bar")).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the name, but what you are describing is actually two seperate functions. `myFunc` simply returns another function.

The line `factory.myFunc("foo")("bar")` first runs the myFunc funtion with `foo` as a parameter, this returns another function, which is then immediately run with the parameter `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

It takes 2 parentheses & 1 argument to call `myFunc`, you need other 2 parentheses & 1 argument to call function it returns.

This sequence of calls is commonly called *chaining* of function calls. Sometimes, this sequence of actions is also referred to as *pipe*.

There's also such a term as `currying` but I'd say it rather describes a technique of declaring functions in a special way that enables you to pass arguments 1 by 1.

In this case, however, I wouldn't say it's currying since `myFunc` does something that has nothing to do with what returned function does while in currying (as it understood in Lodash for instance) all intermediate function calls serve just for passing arguments while the only function that does some actual job after collecting all arguments is the last one.

I would call `myFunc` just "*method* of `factory`".

It's also a *higher order function* as @[ASDFfgerte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6692606/asdfgerte) correctly points out in comment.